# json decode can not be used

Tags: php, json

I have problems in converting the data json into an array.

My code

```
$url = "http://pondokprogrammer.com/image.php";
//  Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();
// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Execute
$result=curl_exec($ch);
// Closing
curl_close($ch);

$decode = json_decode($result);
echo "<pre>".print_r($decode,1)."</pre>";
```

json data like this

```
[
    {
     submit_time: "1433919003.5213"
    },
    {
     submit_time: "1433940260.0048"
    }
]
```

when I run the returning NULL or the data does not show anything, I've tried with

```
trim ();

stripslashes ();

mb_convert_encoding ($ result, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
```

same result when I run always returning NULL
Can anyone can help me ...?
thank you

Comment: That is not valid json. And your url seems to return `print_r()` output instead of anything even remotely similar to json or the non-valid json you have shown. And it seems your script is querying itself for input...

Comment: oh... thank you for helping me, I know now

Answer (score 0):

Your link `http://pondokprogrammer.com/image.php` is echoing PHP array formatted with `<pre>`. You need to `echo json_encode($array)` in your `image.php`